# Create Expression for Entity Framework 6 for JSON column in SQL

Tags: json, entity-framework-6, expression

In a .NET Framework application using Entity Framework 6, I would like to write a SQL query lambda expression as follows:

```
var result = DbContext.Register
    .Where(r => r.Metadata.JsonValue("$.CONTRACT") == 123456)
    .ToList();
```

I want to intercept the expression and write an SQL command like this:

```
public class DbSetInterceptor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
    {
        BinaryExpression expression;

        //WRITE EXPRESSION FOR "JSON_VALUE(Metadata, '$.CONTRACT') = 123456"
        //expression = Expression.MakeBinary(...);

        return base.VisitBinary(expression);
    }
}
```

How to write an expression that translates the **JSON_VALUE** command?